# jsp import & js variables

Tags: javascript, jsp, variables, import

is it possible to output c:import into a Javascript variable?
I have a file.jsp, which contains an html object that I need to append to various places, something along the lines of:

```
<script>
  var element = <c:import url="file.jsp"/>;
  $("body").append($element);
</script>
```

I do understand that this is most likely because I need to somehow contain / escape the imported file, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the contents of file.jsp change depending on where it's being loaded on the page?  Why not accomplish the same thing with a callback?

For example:

$.get('file.jsp', function(data) {
  $('body').append(data);
});

And of course if it's the same content being used many times implement some sort of caching.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find a way for JavaScript, unfortunately I failed to find a solution.  I hope someone can suggest using this way I also want to see how to to this.

As an alternative solution, you can load the content of `file.jsp` into `div` which `hidden` by default. Then get its innerHTML and append it to your HTML.

**HTML**

```
//Your div that hold the Content.jsp
<div id="content" style="display:none">
    <c:import url="Content.jsp" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var element = $('#content').html(); //Store the value of content div to a variable         
     $('body').append(element); //append the element to body
 });
```